# spectrum and degree sequence

Tags: tag-removed, spectral-graph-theory

We have the spectrum and the degree sequence of one graph.
Can we uniquely determine the graph with these given information?

Comment: Do you mean Laplacian spectrum or adjacency spectrum? In any case, most examples of cospectral pairs also have the same degree sequence.

Comment: I do not think it is true that in most examples of cospectral pairs
the graphs have the same degree sequence. It's not true for small
numbers of vertices, $(n\le 9 say?). I suspect that many do have the same degree sequence, but I've never seen a discussion of the matter.
For larger $n$ your guess might be as good as mine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. One simple class of examples are Latin square graphs. If $L$ is an $n\times n$ Latin
square with entries from $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, the vertices of Latin square graph are the $n^2$
triples; two triples are adjacent if the agree on one of their three coordinates. This is
a regular graph of valency $3(n-1)$. In fact these graphs are strongly regular, and their
eigenvalues are $3(n-1)$, $n$ and $-3$ with respective multiplicities 1, $n-3$ and $n^2-3n+2$.
Two Latin squares give non-isomorphic graphs in they are in different main classes
(see the wikipedia article) and there are many main classes for large $n$. When $n=4$
there are two, and over a quarter of a million when $n=8$.

You can find some of the theory on line at 
   http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/spielman/561/lect23-09.pdf

Comment: I think it is true if we know our graph has at least n(n-1)/K(G) edges, where V(G)=n and 2=<K(G)=<3

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is $K(G)$? 

Comment: I defined K(G),K(G) is the set of numbers related to the graph G, that with some given information about G, uniquely determine the graph. In this case, if we have adjacency spectrum and degree sequence, if K(G) be a number in closed interval [2,3], or our graph have approximately n(n-1)/K(G) edges, the graph uniquely is determinable. I am finding the interval of K(G) with some probabilistic method.
In general, we have the spectrum and the property P(G) of graphs G. I am finding the minimum number of edges, that force the graph be unique.      

Comment: I still do not know what $K(G)$ is. But if $q$ is a prime power congruent to 1 mod 4, then there are conference graphs on $q$ vertices which are strongly regular with valency $(q-1)/2$. There are non-isomorphic conference graphs on 25 and 29 vertices (and infinitely many other orders, look for Peisert graphs. Conference graphs on the same number of vertices are cospectral.

Comment: My conjecture is:
If we have the spectrum of graph $G$ and this graph has approximately 
$|V(G)|(|V(G)|-1)/K(G)$ edges, where $K(G) in [2,3]$, this graph is uniquely determinable.
for example, if $K(G)=2$, we have $G=K_n$ and the conjecture is true.
Your previous example, Conference graph, has $q(q-1)/4$ edges and doesn't have the conditions of conjecture.
Do you think this conjecture be true? 

Comment: OK, so the complements of Latin square graphs will be counterexamples for large $n$, since they are regular with valency $n^2-3n+2$ on $n^2$ vertices.

Comment: Dear professor Godsil
Thank you very much for your answers and guidance.